# createdb: could not connect to database template1: fatal: password authentication failed for user "user1"

Tags: postgresql, django-models

I just installed postgres. and then wrote the following commands in my terminal then

postgres@user /home/user $ createuser -dP CinemaHole

Enter password for new role:

Enter it again:

postgres@user /home/user $ createdb -E utf8 -U Movie CinemaHole

createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "Movie"

Here is my pg_hba.conf

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrwCH.png)
Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First do not image links for file contents. Instead post the actual text. It makes it easier to include your information in the answer.

Second try:

`createdb -E utf8 -U CinemaHole -h localhost Movie`

Assuming `CinemaHole` is the user you really want to use.

The connection that is not working:

`createdb -E utf8 -U Movie CinemaHole`

is failing because you do not have a `-h` (host) name so it trying the local socket and your pg_hba.conf has peer authentication for local(socket) connections. Also you are doing `-U Movie` which is specifying the user `Movie` which is not what you created. Also user `Movie` is not the system user you are logged in as, so `peer` authentication is failing. The connection I suggested you try is using `-h localhost` and for that your pg_hba.conf use md5(password) authentication.

For more information on `pg_hba.conf` see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

FYI, you can also do the `CREATE ROLE(USER)` and `CREATE DATABASE` using the `psql` client. Fewer programs to remember.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ,it worked perfectly after localhost there but can you explain why localhost please..

Comment: The best thing for you do is read the docs at the pg_hba.conf  link I posted above. It will explain this and more.  Short answer is `localhost` forces a `host` connection and they use `md5`(password) authentication in your `pg_hba.conf` setup.